# Refresh Rate Nvidia

Tags: graphics

Can someone explain to me how to make my Nvidia settings stick when I change the Nvidia settings to use 120hz? After a reboot the setting is lost and I have to manually go and change it to 120hz every time.

Answer (score 1):

Open Nvidia X Server Settings

[image]

Set there resolution and refresh rate and press "Save to X Configuration File".

Enter there path `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Oh, what is the "save to X Configuration File" thing? Is that just like the boot file for the Nvidia settings? I will test this tonight.

Comment: This is the file with xserver configuration, If you have hybryd graphics, I will suggest to backup it first.

Comment: Yes this doesn't work. After a reboot, the resolution is reset back to auto.

Comment: Where is the refresh rate setting on that screenshot?? Am I blind?